# Changing behavior of icons pinned to taskbar when clicked

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons, pinning

When an application is pinned to the taskbar, an icon is placed at the left side of the taskbar.

[image]

My preference is for those icons to act as a launcher, opening a new window of that application in a separate window. The following shows what it should look like after clicking the Chrome icon.

[image]

The following shows what it should look like after clicking the explorer icon.

[image]

As you can see in pics 2 and 3, the new application windows do not merge with the pinned to taskbar icons.

The following shows the merging behavior that I want to change. It shows what it looks like after clicking the Firefox icon, which then merges the new application window with the pinned taskbar icon. So I can't launch another Firefox window using the pinned taskbar icon, because the icon is gone. It has been replaced/merged with the application window.

[image]

I know it's possible to change the pinned taskbar icon behavior to act as a launcher. I know because I did it for the explorer icon, the MS Word icon, the RDP icon, and the chrome icon (see pics 2 and 3). But I can't remember how I did it, and I can't find anything on the web.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having this issue, pinning the NEW window that opened up and deleting the old one always works for me.